# Change attach icon into loading icon while attaching file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the attach icon into loading and then change it into check icon after attaching the file.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary fileinput-button" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-original-title="Import">
     <i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <input id="fileupload" class="fileupload" type="file" name="files">
</button>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to actually upload the file

Comment: Sorry. I don't have also the idea on the upload part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button").on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this).find(".fa");
    $this.removeClass("fa-paperclip").addClass("fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin");
    setTimeout(function() {// or do your ajax stuff here
       $this.removeClass("fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin").addClass('fa-paperclip');
    },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using a class to show an icon here's what you can do

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("YourElementHere").addClass("fa fa-loading");//just a sample

    //then if you have ajax here on Success function include below code
    //$("YourElementHere").removeClass("fa fa-loading"); //remove the class for loading
    //$("YourElementHere").addClass("fa fa-check"); //add the icon check

});
```